# How to access ansible controller hostname or ip?

Tags: ansible

I need to know the hostname or IP of the machine where ansible was invoked, not the ones from the inventory.

What is the easiest way to access this? Please note that I need to use this variable in tasks that executed on various hosts.

Note that all these are not valid answers:
- `ansible_hostname`
- `inventory_hostname`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use lookups, they are always executed on localhost.

For example: `{{lookup("pipe","hostname")}}`

If you use this value extensively, better to do `set_fact` first, otherwise lookup command will be executed every time it is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

while using in set_fact: use the quotes appropriately I had issue with quotes and below worked for me

```
controller_host: "{{lookup('pipe','hostname')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this method only works on a standalone Ansible controller/node, or AWX (Ansible Tower). But how to do this on the new Ansible Automation Platform (AAP)? For instance, I need to know the name used in the URL of the AAP instance where the job was run. And in general case it can point to a load balancer endpoint. It does not seem is a built-in var that would contain the name.